# Transition between different presentation styles for a UIViewController using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm trying to create an affect where I present a UIViewController as a popover and then animate that view controller into a few different modal presentation styles.

I have successfully presented the view as a popover, and then after dismissing the view re presented it as a full screen overlay but I'm having trouble finding a workflow that allows me to transition without first dismissing the view controller.

I've included an illustration below showing the kind of effect I'd like to achieve where a single view controller transitions between 3 presentation styles, A, B, & C without being dismissed.

In the illustration A represents a `popover` modal presentation style, B `custom`, and C `fullScreen`

[image]
It's worth noting that these particular modal presentation styles are not important, rather that I would like to be able to transition between many kind of modal presentation style for a single view controller without first dismissing it.

What would be the best way to approach this kind of transition?

Comment: I guess `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate ` always best option, but requires manual configuration

Comment: I've been reading about that delegate and finding the docs hard to parse. Do you know if the idea would be to have one view controller transition from state to state, or to have a different view controller for each state with presentation animations that begin from the previous view controllers position?

Comment: Your transition is very strange. A is B ? Or A is not B, then why A is not B? Why A become C. No matter how strange, Github Hero will help you.

Comment: @dengApro Github hero looks great, I'll definitely check it out, though I'd first like to understand how to achieve this without a library before adding a dependency to properly understand the tradeoff. I've also added some detail to the post on the illustration

Comment: @jonathan topf， still  a little hard to image the animation.